# Bind and unbind a bound function to an event

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, underscore.js, bind

I am using [EventEmitter2](https://github.com/hij1nx/EventEmitter2) as message bus internal within my application. Now I need to bind and unbind some event handlers. As I want them also to [bind](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) them to a given context, I end up with the following syntax:

```
messageBus.on('foo::bar', _.bind(eventHandler, this));
```

The problem is that I need to unbind them at a later point in time, so I wrote:

```
messageBus.off('foo::bar', _.bind(eventHandler, this));
```

Unfortunately this does not work, as `_.bind` each time returns a new instance of the wrapper function. Now of course I could run `_.bind` once and bind the wrapped function, such as this:

```
var fn = _.bind(eventHandler, this);
messageBus.on('foo::bar', fn);
messageBus.off('foo::bar', fn);
```

This works perfectly well, but if you have a few event handlers, the code quickly starts to get less readable than necessary.

How might you solve this without the need to externalize the call to the `bind` function? Is there an alternative function that always returns the same wrapper in case you call it multiple times and the function as well as the context are the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Underscore.js provides a `bindAll` method just for this use-case, from the [documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll):

> Binds a number of methods on the object, specified by methodNames, to be run in the context of that object whenever they are invoked

Failing that, you could make use of a closure which always returns the same bound function when invoked, ie:

```
function getOrCreateBoundEventHandlerFor(eventType, callback) { 

    // Initialise the handler map if it's not already been created.
    this._boundEventHandlerMap = this._boundEventHandlerMap || {};

    // If no handler was mapped, create a new one.
    if (this._boundEventHandlerMap[eventType] === void 0) {
        this._boundEventHandlerMap[eventType] = _.bind(callback, this);
    }

    return this._boundEventHandlerMap[eventType];
}
```